# find video cards

Tags: c#

How can I detect all the  avalable videocards in my system ? Example: pixelview

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394583(VS.85).aspx) [Win32_VideoController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394512(VS.85).aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve this information using the [AdapterInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb281503.aspx) class and the DirectX SDK.

[Here](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial127_List-display-adapters-using-DirectX-9.html) is some example code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you need, but you can enumerate all hardware using WMI:

[CodeProject 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/wmiadmin.aspx)
[CodeProject 2](http://69.10.233.10/KB/cs/EverythingInWmi03.aspx)